# Trying to install Kali Linux on QEMU-KVM (using virt-manager) fails on no display

Tags: kali-linux, kvm, qemu, libvirt, virt-manager

I'm trying to install the [bare metal ISO of Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-bare-metal) on virt-manager. The iso boots to the installation menu, but choosing graphical installation fails on no display error as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Non-graphical installation works, but the disk does not boot.

I've managed to install Ubuntu 22.04, so I believe it's an issue that's specific to Kali.

Error when trying to install Kali (captured with OCR from a screenshot):

```
ga=788 initrd=/install .amd/gtk/initrd.gz --- quiet
xorg-server 2:21.1.3-2+b1 Chttps://wuw.debian.org/support )
current version of pixman: 0.40.0
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
jarkers: (--) probed, («) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (77) unknown.
(==) Log file: “vvar/log/Xorg.0.log”, Time: Thu Aug 4 20:24:27 2022
(==) Using system config directory “/usr/share/X11/xorg .conf .d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found (EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
at http://wiki.x.org
pny a3
(EE) Please also check the log file at “/var/log/Xorg.0.log” for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
(debconf :1572): Gtk-WARNING x: : cannot open display: :0
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.3
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 9
urrent Operating System: Linux (none) 5.16.0-kali?—amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 5.16.18-1kali1 (2022-04-01) x86_64
Kernel] command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/install.amdvumlinuz net.ifnames=0 preseed/file=/cdrom/simple-cdd/default .preseed simple-cdd/profiles=kali,offline desktop=xfce
ga=788 initrd=/install .amd/gtk/initrd.gz --- quiet
xorg-server 2:21.1.3-2+b1 Chttps://wuw.debian.org/support )
urrent version of pixman: 0.40.0
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
jarkers: (--) probed, («) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (77) unknown.
(==) Log file: “vvar/log/Xorg.0.log"”, Time: Thu Aug 4 20:24:28 2022
(==) Using system config directory “/usr/share/X11/xorg .conf .d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found (EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
at http://wiki.x.org
pny a3
(EE) Please also check the log file at “/var/log/Xorg.0.log” for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
(debconf : 1597): Gtk-WARNING **: : cannot open display: :0
```

System info:

- OS: Manjaro 21.3.6
- Kernel: 5.15.57-2
- virt-manager version: 4.0.0
- QEMU version: 7.0.0
- Display server: spice

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to solve this by changing the display interface on virt-manager from Virtio to QXL.

After manually changing to QXL, the 3d acceleration setting is still on as a left-over from Virtio, so go to XML mode and remove the line responsible for it.

The final XML in my case is:

```
<video> <model type="qxl" ram="65536" vram="65536" vgamem="16384" heads="1" primary="yes"/> <alias name="video0"/> <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/></video>
```

After applying the changes, Kali booted successfully.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that for future readers +1

Answer (score -1):

I am really thankful for the above comment by @qjxpsrgwp. **That answer did really helped.**

I was having the **exact same issue** as the OP (the original poster) but then I Found the comment and then I just  **followed these steps**.

1. **Open the virtual Machine** > Click on the **show virtual machine details** icon( i.e. a message with and i inside of it).
2. Now you will be in the Overview section, then **go to the Video Section**(there's a monitor icon there.) > Then **Open the module option** and you will see may option there and along with that **you will have the QXL choose that** and then its **voila** for me.

I didn't had to change any XML settings.

Mine default XML settings are :

**You won't see the same settings until you have restarted the machine after the restart these settings will appear so don't panic before.**

Now I don't know the details of what changing the Video Module does but will dig into it a little bit.

I was able to run **Ubuntu without any issues** same as the OP.

**My Host :**

OS: Arch Linux x86_64

Kernel: 6.0.9-arch1-1

DE: Plasma 5.26.3

Qemu-system-x86: 7.1.0-10

Kali: 22.03

I literally came across this answer a few times but didn't game much attention but at last after nothing was found I paid the attention and in 5 minutes my system was working so my lesson is always pay a little attention and some time to the google top results even if they are not popular ones.

I was looking for the answer for pretty long time.

Thanks, it would have been better if you could have explained a little bit.

**Edit: You will have something like 1024x768 resolution by default to change this do this don't right click on the desktop.**

Open Settings Manager (by clicking on the top left) > Go to Display (Hardware Section) > **Change the resolution to your needs.**

And after finishing the GUI installation of kali in the Qemu with QXL video module. I changed it **back to virtio** with 3D Accelaration deisabled and its **working fine for now**.

I found this really **[helpful article](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2019/09/display-devices-in-qemu/)** do read if you want to know more.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/430143)

Comment: Did you read my full answer?I have added some extra stuff in there along with the original answer and explained it a bit further. I have given more details to the answer and just started my answer with ThankYou? What's wrong in that.